# How to remove the edge of shadeless object?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, shadows

I am trying to somewhat paint my object to a pure color. However, there is always a contour around it like [image]

On the top, there is mug that I changed to pure yellow. However, I can always see the black edge around it after rendering. Is there any way to remove it?

Appreciated!

Comment: Try this - Select the mug, go to it's properties at right and open the "Display" tab. (it's down a fair way)  Either tick or untick it's "Transparency" box.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But no it does not remove the thing. I just want to paint the object to a color for labeling. Anyway to work around that?

Comment: If you're working in Blender's 3D window and wish to texture/label the mug, the 'shadeless' box is ticked as a rule.  Then you add a texture slot for the image.  I have no idea what method you are using.  Nodes and Cycles perhaps?

Comment: Great!  Can you tell us how you did it so we can learn?  Add it as an answer below.

Comment: Yes, you can check it below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution which is quite simple.

Basically, when I change the color in Diffuse, I input the RGB in the range of 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 255. I guess Blender has some algorithm to handle it, which I am not quite sure.